# Why is Mysql's left join condition not being honoured?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, where-clause

Orders table:

```
+----------------+
| Field          |
+----------------+
| orderNumber    |
| customerNumber |
+----------------+
```

OrderDetails Table:

```
+-----------------+
| Field           |
+-----------------+
| orderNumber     |
| productCode     |
+-----------------+

SELECT 
    o.orderNumber, 
    o.customerNumber, 
    d.orderNumber,
    d.productCode
FROM
    orders o
LEFT JOIN orderdetails d 
    ON ((o.orderNumber = d.orderNumber) AND (o.orderNumber = 10123)) ;
```

Result:

[image: Results]

I am expecting to see rows which have an orderNumber of only 10123.

Why are we seeing other order numbers included?

The condition of the join (i.e. `o.orderNumber = 10123`) should have excluded those other rows.

I could add `o.orderNumber = 10123` into a WHERE clause, which would fix the problem, but it should work as expected when included in the ON clause. Because the condition would return false given that o.orderNumber IS NOT 10123, and thus should be excluded from the result set.

The MySQL database:
https://sp.mysqltutorial.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/mysqlsampledatabase.zip

Online version where you can type in commands:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/

Comment: there are a few types of join... you need to understand the usage before using them...

Comment: Your syntax is a bit odd..  Don't include the (o.orderNumber = 10123) inside your ON clause.   Move it to a WHERE after the join.

Comment: I'd move the `o.orderNumber = 10123` out of the `JOIN` and into a `WHERE` since it has no bearing on the table you're joining

Comment: You are using the `(o.orderNumber = 10123)` on the JOIN itself, not as a `WHERE o.orderNumber = 10123`.

Comment: Explain why you expect what you expect or you are just asking for yet another presentation of LEFT JOIN & without our knowing where your misunderstandings/misconceptions are. Justify what you expect by reference to authoritative documentation or you haven't appropriately researched & explained. This is a code question so please give a [mre]. That includes the preceding plus code & output as text we can cut & paste & run & diff from your post & that you cut & pasted & ran. PS LEFT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Know which INNER JOIN ON.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please put everything needed to ask in your post, not just at a link & especially not in a file, including a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091641/3404097)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter the resultset on a given order number, youw ant that condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN orderdetails d ON d.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
WHERE o.orderNumber = 10123;
```

This brings all orders for the given number, along with the corresponding order details. If there are no order details, you still get the order row(s) for the given number. If there is no order for that number, the resultset is empty.

Comment: ...either this, or just change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` !

Comment: @Ergis: yes, but this would filter out orders that have no details.

Comment: I already know. I just said an alternative, it's his choice !

Comment: @GMB thx for your answer - my confusion is that the condition in the "ON" clause should still exclude rows which are not `10123`, shouldn't it? This is because that the clause would return a FALSE value Mysql would then omit that row? I am wondering why we must filter using a WHERE clauses, when the same condition could be filtered out using the ON clause. clarifications would be much appreciated. chrs

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: it excludes rows wich are not `10123` *in the left join*, not in the outer query. For this, you want a `where` clause. Or, use `inner join`, and you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Short story, you are requesting all records from the `orders` table. Your join clause will get the data from `orderdetails` only when you have a matching `orderNumber` and when the `orderNumber` is `10123`, but you will still get all the records from `orders`.

If you want to get the records from `orders` only when `orderNumber` is `10123`, you should use a condition for that on the `orders` table. The common way to do this would be to use a `WHERE` clause.

When using a `LEFT JOIN` you will get matching records (based on a condition) from the joined table but you will still get all records from the *LEFT* table.

This should work.

```
SELECT 
    o.orderNumber, 
    o.customerNumber, 
    d.orderNumber,
    d.productCode
FROM
    orders o
LEFT JOIN orderdetails d 
    ON (o.orderNumber = d.orderNumber) 
WHERE o.orderNumber = 10123;
```

Comment: This is an improvement. (But it's still unclear. Eg what is "fetching"? You use it where some input appears as subrows of output rows. Nobody would know that from "fetch". The rest is similarly fuzzy. To be clear & complete one must use enough words to actually say what one means & not just say unclear stuff vaguely consistent with some of it. See also the version at the time of this comment of the other answer I commented on. Not clear. Incomplete.)

Answer (score 1):

"The LEFT JOIN clause allows you to query data from multiple tables. It returns all rows from the left table and the matching rows from the right table. If no matching rows found in the right table, NULL are used." (https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-left-join/). Therefore there is no much to expect from "ON" conditions indeed. For LEFT JOIN they are only about the 2nd table. I'd recommend the author to get better knowledge of kinds of JOINs

Comment: That is not a clear explanation of left join. Eg contrary to the quote, none of the returned rows are input rows. Eg the returned rows contain input rows as subrows, but you don't say which or how exactly. Also this answer doesn't connect what you quote to the asker's confusions or expectations. Also your writing is unclear & vague. Also see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `JOIN` to filter results that don't match in the second table, then use an *inner* join:

```
SELECT o.orderNumber, o.customerNumber, d.orderNumber, d.productCode
FROM orders o JOIN
     orderdetails d 
     ON o.orderNumber = d.orderNumber 
WHERE o.orderNumber = 10123;
```

Outer joins are used when you want to include rows that do not match.

The filtering on `orderNumber` can be in either the `ON` clause or `WHERE` clause -- they are equivalent for an *inner* join.  However, I think it is more "traditional" to put such filtering on a single table in the `WHERE` clause.